# How to access three elements at a time in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, slice, chunks

I am having an issue with slicing from an array within a loop. What I am trying to do is iterate through an array and for each day return 3 different sections from the array. So for example day one should return 0,1,2 day 2 should return 3,4,5 etc... I am using `array_slice()` and it works for the first iteration, but on subsequent iterations, it only returns an array with 1 item in it. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Here is what I currently have:

```
foreach ($days as $day) {
    $j = $j + 1;
    var_dump("j" . $j);
    $activities = array_slice($activities, $j, $number_of_activities);
    var_dump("day" . $day);
    var_dump($activities);
}
```

This is what is returned from var_dump...

```
string(2) "j1"
string(4) "day1"
array(3) {
  [0]=> int(1)
  [1]=> int(2)
  [2]=> int(3)
}
string(2) "j2"
string(4) "day2"
array(1) {
  [0]=> int(3)
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what is in `$days` to begin with? That said, note what you said in your post: for day `d` you want a slice `d-1`, `d`, `d+1`, so why not write your code to do that?

Comment: lol  agree ... please provide the $days array so we can test the code with your values.

Comment: `array_chunks($days, 3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's doing what it should.  Your reassigning activities to the slice result.  So on the second iteration the array has 3 elements, you're starting at index two, so your slice only has one element (the last).  I think you have a logic error.  You probably need a temporary variable to hold the slice instead of overwriting activities.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kris, I'd be using `array_chunk()` for this task.  The reason is that if you use `array_chunk()` outside of your loop, it is a one-and-done function call and you can access it as much as you like via the chunk's index.  Using `array_slice()` inside of your loop will mean a function call on each iteration and this will be less efficient, hence not best practice.

Consider [these demos](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e60a5daffaab309639bffde41c61b0deec69f68):

**Demo #1:** more activities than needed, but no problems:

```
$days=[1,2,3];
$activities=['Poker','Blackjack','Omaha','Pinochle','500','Euchre','Canasta','Hearts','Spades','Multitaire'];
$activities_per_day=3;
$activity_sets=array_chunk($activities,$activities_per_day);

foreach($days as $i=>$d){
    echo "Day: $d, Activities: ",implode(', ',$activity_sets[$i]),"\n";
}
/*
Day: 1, Activities: Poker, Blackjack, Omaha
Day: 2, Activities: Pinochle, 500, Euchre
Day: 3, Activities: Canasta, Hearts, Spades
*/
```

**Demo #2:** not enough activities to fill last day, but no problems:

```
$days=[1,2,3];
$activities=['Poker','Blackjack','Omaha','Pinochle','500','Euchre','Canasta'];
$activities_per_day=3;
$activity_sets=array_chunk($activities,$activities_per_day);

foreach($days as $i=>$d){
    echo "Day: $d, Activities: ",implode(', ',$activity_sets[$i]),"\n";
}
/*
Day: 1, Activities: Poker, Blackjack, Omaha
Day: 2, Activities: Pinochle, 500, Euchre
Day: 3, Activities: Canasta
```

**Demo #3:** last day has no activities -- causes problems:

```
$days=[1,2,3];
$activities=['Poker','Blackjack','Omaha','Pinochle','500','Euchre'];
$activities_per_day=3;
$activity_sets=array_chunk($activities,$activities_per_day);

foreach($days as $i=>$d){
    echo "Day: $d, Activities: ",implode(', ',$activity_sets[$i]),"\n";
}
/*
Day: 1, Activities: Poker, Blackjack, Omaha
Day: 2, Activities: Pinochle, 500, Euchre
Day: 3, Activities: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
*/
```

Comment: @JavaStudent I just happened to revisit this page today.  My output is what you want to do, right?  Then it is better coding practice to use `array_chunk` once instead of `array_slice()` each iteration in the loop.  Am I confused about your task?